# ow to restrict selection of same record for second time(many2many) in one2many?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x95Az.png)when i select selection field value like day-1 in tree view one2many field and should not repeat day-1 it should start with day-2   'day': fields.selection([(1,'Day-1'), (2,'Day-2'), (3,'Day-3'),(4,'Day-4'), (5,'Day-5')],'Day'), in odoo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUs3d.png)

Comment: add default="2"

Comment: in image repeated records showing should not show

Comment: you can proceed with onchange

Comment: should not repeat the select field values

Comment: can u send me example for selections field

Comment: no idea..................

Comment: @api.onchange('day')
    def _day_change(self):
        res= {}
        if self.env.context.get('day'):
            crm_team_members_ids = self.env[current_model].search([('day', 'in', self.env.context.get('dat')[0][2])])
            crm_sp_ids= crm_team_members_ids.ids
            userlist = list(set(crm_sp_ids))

Comment: above code some what my idea after that you need to pass domain which remaining

Comment: @api.onchange('day')
    def _day_change(self):
        res= {}
        if self.env.context.get('day'):
            crm_team_members_ids = self.env[current_model].search([('day', 'not in', self.env.context.get('dat')[0][2])])
            crm_sp_ids= crm_team_members_ids.ids
            dayslist = list(set(crm_sp_ids))
            res['domain'] = {'day':[ dayslist]}
            return res

Comment: you can try with this code

Comment: same selection field values are repeating..plz show above screenshot

Answer (score 0):

@api.onchange('week1_meals_id','week2_meals_id','week3_meals_id','week4_meals_id')
    def _onchange_amount(self):
        days =[]

```
    if len(self.week1_meals_id) >5 or len(self.week2_meals_id) >5 or len(self.week3_meals_id) >5 or len(self.week4_meals_id) >5:
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'),_('Only 5 days per week!!'))

    for lp in [self.week1_meals_id, self.week2_meals_id, self.week3_meals_id, self.week4_meals_id]:
        for i in lp:
            if i.day in days:
                raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'),_('Meals for this day already exists!!'))
            else:
                days +=[ i.day]
```